# Scala Recursion

Tags: scala

How could I write function below in regular Recursion and Tail Recursion.

```
def satisfiesAllIt(x: List[Any], test: Any => Boolean): Boolean = {
    var satisfies = 0
    for (i <- 0 until x.length) {
      if (test(x(i))) satisfies += 1
    }
    satisfies == x.length
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried it yourself ? If yes .. where are you stuck ?

Comment: A great question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic recursive version.

```
def satisfiesAllIt(x: List[Any], test: Any => Boolean): Boolean =
  if (x.isEmpty) true
  else if(test(x.head)) satisfiesAllIt(x.tail, test) && true
  else false
```

Here's a tail recursive version.

```
def satisfiesAllIt(x: List[Any], test: Any => Boolean): Boolean =
  if (x.isEmpty) true
  else if(test(x.head)) satisfiesAllIt(x.tail, test)
  else false
```

And this is what you do after you've studied the Standard Library.

```
def satisfiesAllIt(x: List[_], test: Any => Boolean): Boolean = x.forall(test)
```

---

@The Archetypal Paul makes a good point (as he often does) and has offered an alternative.

```
// basic recursive
def satisfiesAllA(x: List[Any], test: Any => Boolean): Boolean =
  x.isEmpty || satisfiesAllA(x.tail, test) && test(x.head)

// tail recursive
def satisfiesAllB(x: List[Any], test: Any => Boolean): Boolean =
  x.isEmpty || test(x.head) && satisfiesAllB(x.tail, test)
```

What we're all dancing around, without actually pointing it out, is the defining difference between basic and tail recursion: if there's any more "work" to be done after the recursive call returns (calculations/evaluations/etc.) then it is **not** tail recursive.

Comment: The `&& true`` just to make it non-tail-recursive is a bit of hack  :) If you want a non-tail-recursive one, better to emulate the OP's function and do the count?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul, I don't disagree.  I felt it _might_ be more instructive to have the two versions as similar as possible so as to better illustrate the core difference.

Comment: I dont think it does illustrate the difference. The "&&ttrue" isn't there for any algorithmic reason  `= x,isEmpty|| (satisfiesAll(x.tail, test) && test(x.head))` is a succinct and non-tail-recursive verson?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tail recursive version of the `satisfiesAllIt`. The idea is to call the function recursively until the list is over and return `false` if test fails.

```
def satisfiesAllIt(x: List[Any], test: Any => Boolean): Boolean = xs match {
  case Nil => true
  case x :: xs =>
    if (test(x)) satisfiesAllIt(xs, test) else false
}
```

Comment: You don't need to count them. You just need to stop when the first one doesn't satisfy

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul  Ya you are right .. corrected it :)

Comment: And if you pass `test` to your `helper` too you find you don't need the helper function but can just have `satisfiesAllIt` :)

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul got it ... edited the answer thanks :)

Comment: The last line could be just `test(x) && satisfiesAllIt(xs, test)`